# Is there a way to define color directly without using named colors

Tags: color, inline, tabularray

I am trying to use a background color on `longtblr` of `tabularray` package within `\SetCell` command and it seems I only can used named colors. E.g. the ones defined before with `\definecolor`. I am buidling a generator and would like to use the color defined on the spot.

```
\definecolor{c5E90CB}{HTML}{5E90CB}
...    
\SetCell[r=1,c=3]{bg=c5E90CB,halign=l,valign=h}\makecell{Test instructions and report}
```

I would like to use the color definition directly, without defining it upfront - something like

```
\SetCell[r=1,c=3]{bg=\color[HTML]{5E90CB},halign=l,valign=h}{Test instructions and report}
```

but this is not working.

Thanks, Blaž

Comment: There is an open issue to add this feature (with some discussion on the best syntax) https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/106

Comment: Thank you David. Would it be possible to define the color somewhere in the "cell section"? After the \hline or & and before \SetCell.

Answer (score 6):

> Would it be possible to define the color somewhere in the "cell section"? After the `\hline` or `&` and before `\SetCell`?

Yes, you can use `\NewTableCommand` to create a `\DefineColor` command. Then you can put it at the beginning of cells.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewTableCommand{\DefineColor}[3]{\definecolor{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{lcr}
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma \\
\hline
 \DefineColor{c5E90CB}{HTML}{5E90CB}
 \SetCell[r=1,c=3]{bg=c5E90CB,halign=l,valign=h} Epsilon & & \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly more automated solution that avoids choosing a color name (and also answers [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/709322/14500) more precisely):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcounter{CurrentCellBgColor}
\NewTableCommand{\SetCellBgColor}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{CurrentCellBgColor}%
  \definecolor{CurrentCellBgColor-\theCurrentCellBgColor}{#1}{#2}%
  \SetCell{bg=CurrentCellBgColor-\theCurrentCellBgColor}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{lcr}
  \hline
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma \\
  \hline
  \SetCellBgColor{HTML}{5E90CB}
  \SetCell[r=1,c=3]{halign=l,valign=h} Epsilon & & \\
  \hline
  \SetCellBgColor{HTML}{905eCB}
  \SetCell[r=1,c=3]{halign=c,valign=h} Epsilon & & \\
  \hline
  \SetCellBgColor{rgb}{200,100,0}
  \SetCell[r=1,c=3]{halign=r,valign=h} Epsilon & & \\
  \hline
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]