# Set tblr environment cell color using HTML code directly

Tags: color, tabularray

I have a large autogenerated tex file that includes several tables like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[1,r]|X[1,l]},
    width=0.6\linewidth,
    column{1}={font=\bfseries},
    cell{1}{1} = {r = 2}{valign = m},
    cell{1}{2} = {r = 2}{valign = m},
    cell{3}{1} = {r = 2}{valign = m},
    cell{3}{2} = {r = 2}{valign = m},
    cell{5}{1} = {r = 2}{valign = m},
    cell{5}{2} = {r = 2}{valign = m}
  }
  \hline
  { foo \\ bar } & \SetCell{MyColor} Lorem \\
  & \\ \hline
  { foo \\ bar } & 10 \\
  & \\ \hline
  { foo \\ bar } & 42 \\
  & \\ \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The input to the code that autogenerates this file only contains HTML codes for the colors in the first row (e.g., MyColor).

I realize I can track and define those in a separate file that's included in the document preamble, but I'd rather change the background color directly using the HTML code without doing this.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for adding a minimal document to your question. One thing that's not very clear is what the autogeneration code looks like. I'm sure you could write a small Javascript script to inject the colours from the HTML source into the TeX source, but it would be helpful to see how the generation actually works in practice.

Comment: It is a single section with paragraphs of text separated by exact copies of the table above. It is only the color in the one cell with the \SetCell command I wish to use an HTML code directly.

Comment: But then I don't understand what you mean by "use an HTML code directly". The `xcolor` package supports the HTML colour model, so you can specify a colour using that, but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: \SetColor only takes a color definition, so I have to anticipate all the HTML color codes used in the source and create \definecolor statements for each before I start writing tables that depend on them. I am hoping for an alternate technique to replace \SetCell{MyColor} with \MySetCell[HTML]{63be7b} for example so I can use a random HTML color code to set the background of a cell without defining the color ahead of time.

Comment: @Ritmo2k See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709370/14500)...